# How to control size of matrix brackets

Tags: matrices, brackets, vector

The brackets in this matrix-vector equation have different heights. How can we use a standard size or, even better, ensure that all terms in an equation have a common size?

[image: Matrices with brackets of different sizes.]

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
  %
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 \\
    \end{array}
  \right]
  %
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
     x_{1} \\
     x_{2} \\
    \end{array}
  \right] =
  %
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
     b_{1} \\
     b_{2} \\
    \end{array}
  \right]
  %
  \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Using TexShop 3.5.7, distribution TexLive-2014.

Comment: Sorry, no: I get this [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U5gs1.png)

Comment: @dantopa - Your MWE code does *not* generate the screenshot you've posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `bmatrix` environment to get a matrix with brackets whose height depends only on the number of rows.

```
\begin{equation*}
%
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{1} \\
   x_{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   b_{1} \\
   b_{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

For a few common variants on this, see [Wikibooks LaTeX: matrices](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Here I show it with TABstacks.  I show in the preamble how one can set the inter-column gap, the inter-row baselineskip and the column alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}%               sets gap between columns
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}% sets baselineskip of rows
\def\stackalignment{c}%                  sets column alignment
\begin{document}
\[
  \bracketMatrixstack{21&0\\0&1}  
  \bracketVectorstack{x_1\\x_2} =
  \bracketVectorstack{b_1\\b_2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]